# Pattern to reuse JS variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns

I am missing some piece in the understand puzzle on where to declare and how to use JS variables later in the lifetime of the webapp

For the example, I have some map layout with markers. In some scope I need to declare the marker objects and add them to the map.

Later in the code, I want to access them, as I can't extract them from the map.

One solution that comes to mind is global variables. 
Another is to create an object to hold those markers, but also that object would need to be global

Is there another way to structure the code so variables would be accessible?

Comment: since about everything in js is an object, you can tack them one anywhere, including the map, the map adder function, the img element that is the map, etc...

Answer (score 0):

One of the standard approaches is a wrapper function acting as your scope:

```
var MyPublicApi = (function() {
  // Scope-global variables
  var mapMarkers = [];

  // All non-public functions
  function myFunction() {
    // Something
  }

  // Initialization stuff
  mapMarkers.push(/* a marker */);

  // Return a public api, e.g. like this
  var api = {
    getMarkers: function() {
      return mapMarkers;
    }
  };
})();
```

The outer function declaration allows you to restrict the visibility of variables which behave like global variables for all the code in the function.

If you don't want to provide any public api, you can use

```
(function() {
  // ...
})();
```

instead of

```
var MyPublicApi = (function() {
  // ...
})();
```

Comment: thanks, but in what scope is MyPublicApi? How can I access it in other code blocks?

Comment: @NickGinanto Assuming you use this in a browser, MyPublicApi will be in the global scope (`window`), so **every** other function or file can use it like this: `var markers = MyPublicApi.getMarkers();`